# Expression must have class type(Student Database)?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to programming C++ and I've been trying to make a program of a student database where the marks of courses completed will be sorted in an ascending order. 
The tricky part here is that the variables I have declared in the class must remain in private. Using the variables in my sort function shows an error saying expression must have class. I don't really know what's the solution to this. Any help is greatly appreciated! :) 
Code is `

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Student{
private:
    int data[100];
    string name;
    string id;
        float cgpa, hcgpa, lcgpa;
        int marks[100];
    int cc; //courses Completed

public:
    int getMarks(void){
        int i = 100;
        int m; 
        return m = marks[i];

    }
    void getInfo(int i){
        cout << "Student " << i << ": " << endl;

        cout << "ID: ";
        cin >> id;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "CGPA: ";
        cin >> cgpa;
        cout << "Number of courses completed: ";
        cin >> cc;
        cout << "Please enter the marks respectively: " << endl;
        for (int j = 1; j <= cc; j++){
            cout << "Mark " << j << ": " << endl;
            cin >> marks[j];

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    void sortMarks(Student z[], int i, int &n){
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            j = i;      
            while (j>0 && z[j - 1].getMarks > z[j].getMarks){
                swap(z.[j - 1]getMarks(), z.[j]getMarks());
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    void showInfo(int i){
        cout << "Student " << i << ": " << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << id << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "CGPA: " << cgpa << endl;
        cout << "Number of courses completed: " << cc << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 1; j <= cc; j++){
            cout << "Marks for course " << j << ": " << endl;
            cout << marks[j] << endl;

        }
    }
};
int main(){
    Student s[100];
    int no; //should be less than 100

    cout << "Number of students: ";
    cin >> no;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        s[i].getInfo(i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        s[i].showInfo(i);
    }
    cout << "After sort: \n" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        s[i].sortMarks(i);
        s[i].showInfo(i);
    }

    system("pause");
    //Error is it doesn't show the exact values after the first student's info.
}
```

`

Comment: As well as Vlad's point (which is probably the problem) you can also make `sortMarks` static - it doesn't need to have a Student record to work. It also looks like you're calling it with the wrong arguments further down. Finally I'd suggest you want to sort an array of `Student*`s rather than `Student`s to avoid so much work for each swap, but it'd still work as here. And you `int &n` doesn't need to be a reference (AFAICS) and - although I can't see a correct call of sortMarks - I'd guess `i < n-1` should just be `i < n`.

Comment: @Rup, I see, I'll fix the arguments as mentioned. The reference I used for is for the int no variable though, but I guess you're right, it's not really required.  I'll try it out and let you know how it goes :). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant

```
swap(z[j - 1].getMarks(), z[j].getMarks());
```

instead of

```
swap(z.[j - 1]getMarks(), z.[j]getMarks());
```

though there is no any sense in this construction because the compiler in any case will issue an error because you are trying to swap temporary objects returned by getMarks.

This member function

```
int getMarks(void){
    int i = 100;
    int m; 
    return m = marks[i];

}
```

is simply invalid and has no any sense.

So the problem with your code is not in the error. The problem is that your code is invalid in whole.

For example function `sortMarks` should be defined as a static member function. You can directly access elements of arrays marks in this function without using getMarks.

Comment: So since the getMarks is the issue, I don't need to write that there yes? I'll get rid of it since it's not working or helping much. I make the sortMarks function static then. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes :). Thanks so much!